# Exclude duplicate data from the PagedList

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am using Play2.0 Framework for the backend API. So i want to list of Rides from the database and i want exclude the Ride which has duplicate "place" name.

I am using this code but this gives me all Rides record that is stored in database. How to exclude dulicate entry?

Here is Java code

```
public List<RideDTO> recent(long userId, int cursor, int count) {
        PagedList<RideDTO> pagedList = RideDTO.find
                .where()
                .eq("user_id", userId)
                .orderBy("created_on desc")
                .findPagedList(cursor, count);
        if (pagedList == null)
            return null;
        else
            return pagedList.getList();
    }
```

And here is the RideDTO model class. I don't want to keep place as unique in database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "m_ride")
//@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"place"})
public class RideDTO extends Model {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@NotNull
@Constraints.Required
private long id;

@ManyToOne
@NotNull
@Constraints.Required
private UserDTO user;

@NotNull
@Constraints.Required
private String place;

@NotNull
@Constraints.Required
private double startLat;

@NotNull
@Constraints.Required
private double startLng;

@NotNull
@Constraints.Required
private double destLat;

@NotNull
@Constraints.Required
private double destLng;

private double currLat;

private double currLng;

@NotNull
@Constraints.Required
private short isFav;

private String image;

@NotNull
@CreatedTimestamp
@Constraints.Required
private Date createdOn;

@Transient
private double distance;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public UserDTO getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(UserDTO user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getPlace() {
    return place;
}

public void setPlace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
}

public double getStartLat() {
    return startLat;
}

public void setStartLat(double startLat) {
    this.startLat = startLat;
}

public double getStartLng() {
    return startLng;
}

public void setStartLng(double startLng) {
    this.startLng = startLng;
}

public double getDestLat() {
    return destLat;
}

public void setDestLat(double destLat) {
    this.destLat = destLat;
}

public double getDestLng() {
    return destLng;
}

public void setDestLng(double destLng) {
    this.destLng = destLng;
}

public double getCurrLat() {
    return currLat;
}

public void setCurrLat(double currLat) {
    this.currLat = currLat;
}

public double getCurrLng() {
    return currLng;
}

public void setCurrLng(double currLng) {
    this.currLng = currLng;
}

public short getIsFav() {
    return isFav;
}

public void setIsFav(short isFav) {
    this.isFav = isFav;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public Date getCreatedOn() {
    return createdOn;
}

public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
    this.createdOn = createdOn;
}

public double getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(double distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RideDTO{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", user=" + user +
            ", place='" + place + '\'' +
            ", startLat=" + startLat +
            ", startLng=" + startLng +
            ", destLat=" + destLat +
            ", destLng=" + destLng +
            ", currLat=" + currLat +
            ", currLng=" + currLng +
            ", isFav=" + isFav +
            ", image='" + image + '\'' +
            ", createdOn=" + createdOn +
            ", distance=" + distance +
            '}';
}

public static final Finder<Long, RideDTO> find = new Finder<Long, RideDTO>(Long.class, RideDTO.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't test code here ( I'm at work )

There are a few options, you could:

- Do it on database level ( my prefered way because it's faster )
- Call to .stream() method and do some sorting

Try this:

```
public List<RideDTO> recent(long userId, int cursor, int count) {
        PagedList<RideDTO> pagedList = RideDTO.find.select("*")
                .where()
                .eq("user_id", userId)
                .orderBy("created_on desc")
                .setDistinct(true)
                .findPagedList(cursor, count);

            return pagedList.getList();
    }
```

Just a few notes, you don't have to return null in Ebean, just check for list.isEmpty() in your view.

Ebean is not going to throw a null pointer exception.

Edit: 
As the comment pointed out, I haven't set the value which should be distincted.

When using **setDistinct** in Ebean we have to use it with **select**.

From the [docs](https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/ExpressionList.html#setDistinct-boolean-)

Set whether this query uses DISTINCT.
The select() clause MUST be specified when setDistinct(true) is set. The reason for this is that generally ORM queries include the "id" property and this doesn't make sense for distinct queries.

```
 List<Customer> customers =
      Ebean.find(Customer.class)
         .setDistinct(true)
         .select("name")     // only select the customer name
         .findList();
```

Comment: You missing the important portion, for which column you applying `DISTINCT`. Here the column is `place`

Comment: Thank you mates. I will check follow this follow answer then will get back to you guys

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue i am still getting repeated rides :(

Comment: Oh, mhh I don't know, it always worked fine for me, you could call the .stream() method on the collection like described here: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.util.stream/Stream/Stream.distinct_.htm

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir, btw. why isn't your method static ? and why isn't it defined in the model ?

Comment: Well its a method inside DAO class. I have make it static. i only used it once. What difference would it make if i declare it static?

Comment: I'm just used to the Ebean style where are methods are declared static inside the model, Check out this example: https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean-example

Comment: thanks for the link. I have tried .stream().distinct() but it doesn't remove duplicate entry :(

Comment: Have you set the property which should be distincted ? like so: .distinct(p -> p.getName());